# Move through PHP calendar months with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I am creating an events calendar in a WordPress theme using [David Walsh's calendar](http://davidwalsh.name/php-event-calendar) function. I want to move between months with AJAX but am unfamiliar and having trouble posting  and getting the month and year variables. I am referencing this [AJAX video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CMTQtnZ0G0).

At the top of the page template, I have this function:

```
    function swapContent(month,year) {
        jQuery("#calendar").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'>").show();
        var url="calendar.php";
        jQuery.post(url, {contentVar: month, year}, function(data){
            jQuery("#calendar").html(data).show();
        });
    }
```

In calendar.php:

```
    $month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
    $year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

    $contentVar = $_POST['month']['year'];
```

And my previous/next month controls look like this:

`$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript: swapContent("month", "year")">Previous Month</a>';`

All of my calendar.php file here: http://pastebin.com/R9zpA3yM

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're setting the month and year correctly. You're passing in "month" and "year" as strings and then not setting them as the right parameter names to pass into your PHP script. Try this:

```
function swapContent(monthVal,yearVal) {
    jQuery("#calendar").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'>").show();
    var url="calendar.php";
    jQuery.post(url, {month: monthVal, year: yearVal}, function(data){
        jQuery("#calendar").html(data).show();
    });
    return false;
}
```

Then in your PHP:

```
$monthVal = ($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12);
$yearVal = ($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1);

$previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.$monthVal.'&year='.$yearVal .'" class="control" onClick="swapContent("'.$monthVal.'","'.$yearVal.'");">Previous Month</a>';
```

Rather than use `onmousedown` I would just have the function in the `onclick`, just make sure it returns false at the end of the function which I've included.

I am not sure how month, year and contentVar are all being used in your PHP script, so the following is an assumption, but it looks like you would just need something along the lines of:

```
$month = (int) ($_POST['month'] ? $_POST['month']
                                : ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] 
                                                  : date('m')));

$year= (int) ($_POST['year'] ? $_POST['year']
                               : ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] 
                                                  : date('Y')));
```

And then use those variables accordingly to get your data?

Comment: Thank you! Still haven't gotten it to work though. Here's my calendar.php file: http://pastebin.com/R9zpA3yM. I noticed the controls are echoed onto the page within `<form>` and `<input>` tags (line 148) - I made them singular links but still no dice. Also, for previous and next month navigation, would I need variables for `prevMonthVal` and `nextMonthVal`? Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, nevermind about the `<input>`. I am also getting this error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : :8888/onlyinpgh/calendar/?month=8&year=2011:11`. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes your links would likely need to reference `prevMonthVal` and `nextMonthVal` as you've described. Not sure about your javascript error, it's stating that it wasn't expecting an :. Looking at the line quoted afterwards that is probably the 2011:11 at the end which is an illegal character in a URL, the : should be encoded as %3A